# What is the key name responsible for the active tab's color?

Tags: sublimetext2

When we open multiple files in SublimeText2, the tab of the currently displayed file is a bit darker/lighter than the rest. My problem is, I cannot see it — the shade difference is too small.

What is the name of the key in the `.tmTheme` file, so I could make it more contrasting? Or is it just a hard-coded effect that I can't influence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab colors are set by images in the .sublime-theme.  The class/attribute you are concerned with is

```
{
    "class": "tab_control",
    "attributes": ["selected"],
    "layer0.texture": "//IMAGE TO USE AS BACKGROUND FOR TAB//",
    "layer1.opacity": 0.0
}
```

But any of the `"class": "tab_control"` properties can be customized.

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same things... My `.tmTheme` file is an XML, not a JSON config file.

Comment: The tab background colors are set in the `.sublime-theme`, not the color scheme `.tmTheme` file.  The default Sublime theme is located in your packages directory in `Theme - Default` folder. Maybe I misunderstood your question?